# Emu8086 programm to check for Array Duplicates

Tags: assembly, emu8086

How to check array duplicates for the array of DIM bytes contains duplicated values
ARRAY db 23, 9, 12, 7, 11, 3
DIM db 6

Comment: By looping over it and keeping track of which values you've encountered. It's not clear exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: There are two main strategies: O(N^2) looping the rest of the array for every element, or using 256 bytes of extra space (number of possible byte values) to make a histogram in O(N) time.